# Nginx downloads PHP files instead of showing them (not a socket issue)

Tags: php, nginx, vps

So I am setting up my first Linode (sort of new to managing everything myself). However, I have the following problem. The browser downloads the php file instead of executing it and MS Internet Explorer shows the file's content instead of downloading it.

I've read through a lot of content/answers about this problem but nothing seems works so I'd appreciate your help.

Important to note is that the website "crashes" only when I add the following line to the Virtual Host file

`location ~* .(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|bmp|zip|woff)$ {
expires 365d;
}`

Here are the two files in full
**NGINX.CONF**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 10s;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

# ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
# ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";


gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

**and the sites-available/default file**

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /www/bloggingwithdani.com;

index index.html index.php index.htm;

server_name localhost;

# pagespeed On;
# pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/";
# pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~* .(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|png|ico|bmp|zip|woff|css|js|)$ {
expires 365d;
}


location ~ /\. {
deny all;
}

location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
deny all;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
return 404;
}
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;

}

}
```

Comment: You need to set a handler for the PHP files. I don't recognize this syntax, so, I can't help much with it. If nginx supports htaccess, I can help you.

Comment: What OS does nginx run on?

Comment: Please accept an answer or add your own answer and accept it. Doing that will prevent appearing this question as unanswered. @Dani

Answer (score 0):

your php location block looks wrong to me. here's my location block for php

```
location ~ \.(php)$ {

    try_files $uri = 404;
    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {return 404;}
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; #passing directly to the socket
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;

}
```

also, your static file caching is wrong, and has an erroneous wild card parameter. remove the last `|` and optionally add some extra configuration options to further optimize delivery of static content.

```
location ~* .(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|png|ico|bmp|zip|woff|css|js)$ {

    expires max;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    access_log off;

}
```